# Seeking free Archaeology datasets?

Tags: data, archaeology

Are there any sites that gather free archaeology datasets?

Comment: Please check these threads http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/open-access-repository-of-general-gis-spatial-data 

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28047/list-of-us-government-free-gis-data-online

Comment: What do you consider to be an archaeology dataset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

Found this [collection of links with some archaeological datasets](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Public_Geodata_for_the_UK). It's just for UK though.

Here's a teaser

```
ARCHAEOLOGICAL DATA
Source – BAA, Oxford Archaeology and Wessex Archaeology.
Data – Archaeological data for Stansted and Heathrow Airports. Excavations by Framework Archaeology 1998 to 2004
Format – Various, including ESRI format.
Licence – Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 2.0 License (see website).
Cost – Free.
Comments –
Link - http://www.framearch.co.uk/stansted/index.html - Stansted Link - http://www.framearch.co.uk/t5/data-downloads/ - Heathrow T5
```

---

Here are some [free archaeological datasets from the Swedish National Data Service](http://snd.gu.se/en/search-and-order-data/gis-data).
[image]

---

This one's from the [La Milpa, Belize](http://web.archive.org/web/20201105232038/http://www.bu.edu/lamilpa/).

[image]

---

Answer (score 5):

A nice training dataset for archaeologists can be found here: https://github.com/kacebe/AtlantGIS

The authors describe AtlantGIS as a collection of

> Faked GIS-Datasets, simulating an island in the Atlantic for
>   educational purposes in using GIS in archaeology. All AtlantGIS data
>   are published under a CC-BY-SA 4.0 license.
>
> The idea is to create artificial data creatively referring to the
>   story of Atlantis as told by Platon. We believe that simple datasets
>   with a narrative are most qualified to impart knowledge and skills to
>   students.
>
> Whoever likes the idea is invited to contribute data using the
>   repository on GitHub. We ask every contributor to link to documents
>   that put the dataset in context of a special GIS-related task and make
>   the tutorials/workshop documents available under an open licence.

We added some tables about pottery to this framework for an R tutorial: 
https://github.com/ISAAKiel/R-Tutorial_CAA2016/tree/master/data

Answer (score 2):

I have collected a list of free vectordata here: http://desktopmapping.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/diverse-vektordaten.html should be useful. although comments are in german

Answer (score 2):

a general site first...freegisdata.rtwilsom.com
go to the country site of interest and find out if they have data.

next site 
Ancient world mapping center
www.uncedu/awmc/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good sites I have been able to get data from in the past.

- http://db.edcs.eu/epigr/epimap.html   (amazing map and data showing locations of found roman inscriptions all over europe, africa, asia)
- https://www.cadb.pitt.edu/cadbregion.html
- https://dougsarchaeology.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/gis-and-archaeology-some-resources-on-learning-gis-for-archaeology/
- http://libguides.brown.edu/c.php?g=293943&p=1957505
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=archeology
- http://www.ascsa.edu.gr/index.php/excavationcorinth/maps-and-gis-data-for-corinth-and-greece
- https://snd.gu.se/en/data-in-focus/archeological-gis-data
- https://osf.io/esjkf/