# Is there a source for free CSV files with geo data and other desired fields?

Tags: csv, data, random, sampling

I'm writing some software components that process geospatial data. The input data is a CSV with general columns (e.g. `name`) and geo columns (e.g. `city`, `lat` or `zip`). I would like to test these components with some thousands of points.

**Is there an online source that generates free csv files with geo data, according to a list of desired fields?**

For example, I would like to have 1,000 points in North America, each with `lat`, `lon`, `city`, `zip` and `state`. Or 5,000 points in Europe, each with `lat` and `lon`.

I will probably build it myself [from free data sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28047/list-of-us-government-free-gis-data-online) if it doesn't exist, but using an existing source would save lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) has some nice datasets, but their columns are fixed.

Comment: Changing the name of the columns wouldn't be hard...

Comment: Correct, but adding extra columns would require tedious geocoding from external services.