# Sample data for testing GEOS bindings

Tags: data, geos, testing

Similarly to this question ([Is there a source for free CSV files with geo data and other desired fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37719/is-there-a-source-for-free-csv-files-with-geo-data-and-other-desired-fields)) I am working on testing an open source set of bindings for the GEOS project and would like to boot strap the process with some existing data and expected outcomes. (this polygon intersect that polygon gives this polygon) type of thing.

Anyone know of any good reference implementations of testing for geo libraries??